# Does each "account" in case of hierarchical deterministic wallet need a unique Solana Token Account to hold SOLs?

Tags: wallet, token-account

In such case, each "account" would require a rent-exempt fees for each Solana Token Account (to pay for 165 bytes storage), is it correct ?

Comment: can you specify what role you imagine the HD wallet keys playing in this scenario? are they going to be used for addressing, authority, delegate, something else?

Comment: For addressing for instance, suppose you want to hold different SPL Tokens inside a single HD wallet, you would create one derived keypair for each SPL Token (1...n) such as m/44/501/[1..n]/0 then you would create a Token Account for each 1..n derived keypair to hold the specific SPL Token; if I'm correct. So total cost would be n x rent-exemption(165).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start, a few words about Solana lingo. I got a bit confused by the wording "Solana Token Account" in your question. What you mean is just called a "Solana Account" or "System Account" in Solana speak. The term "Token Account" is reserved for accounts that hold *token*s, where SOL itself does not count as a *token*.

Any keypair generated by an HD wallet (or otherwise) *might* be useful, e.g. for just signing a transaction without also being the payer.

However, **if** you want the kaypair to be associated with an **account**, whether that's a *System Account* (holding only SOL), a *token account* (holding tokens other than SOL, such as USDC or RAY) or a *Program Derived Address* (PDA) account just holding data for a Solana Program, there will be a need to deposit the rent-exempt amount.

Please note that is amount is not exactly a cost, but more like a deposit, since you will get it back when you close the account.

Comment: What I meant is "if you create many accounts in a HD wallet, to hold different tokens, do you need different accounts on the Solana blockchain (hence the Solana Token Account wording)". I got the answer: each Token Account can hold just 1 type of token (other than SOL), so you need, for each token a rent-exempt amount at creation. In practice, if you plan to hold 1000 NFTs, you'll have to deposit 1000 x rent-exemption amount.

Answer (score 1):

No.

**Every** account may hold the native "token" SOL. There's [a field for it on the account (lamports)](https://docs.rs/solana-program/latest/solana_program/account_info/struct.AccountInfo.html).  A separate token account is only needed if you require access to a [wrapped SOL token](https://explorer.solana.com/address/So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112) for things like trading between SOL and other tokens.

You are correct that rent-exemption (or rent fees) will be required for every new account created.

Comment: What I meant is: on HD wallets, derived keypairs are usually called "accounts", and they are only keypairs, no blockchain presence. My understanding is that we have to create a Token Account for each "account" in the meaning derived keypair to hold SOL tokens. So each derived keypair costs 165 bytes rent-exemption to be useful. Correct ?

Comment: A derived address with no balance _might_ not have a presence on the blockchain and if there's no blockchain presence, there's no rent to be paid. However, as soon as each "account" needs to hold a balance, there _must_ be a blockchain presence. With the token program, each new type of token requires a separate account and each of those would pay rent from the _native_ SOL/lamport balance (which is different from the balance of tokens in the account) or meet the exemption minimum.